# Can I specify *source* IP address for a JDBC connection?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, ip-address

I have a Java application that connects to a database with a JDBC driver. It happens to be a Postgres instance, but I'm looking for a general solution if it exist.

The server on which the application runs has multiple IP address, all in the same subnet. The JDBC connection is established using the 'primary' IP of the server.

I can [play with Linux networking stack](https://serverfault.com/a/182594/81170) to have outgoing connections to the database use the secondary IP address.

Is there a way to programatically specify the **source IP** address will be used to to my JDBC connection?

---

*Context: We want to move the application without touching the database, which has rules restricting IP address it will accept connections from.*

*The only hack I see would be making an SSL connection, and return a new Socket bound to the secondary IP from a custom [SSLSocketFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html).*

Comment: There's a `ClientHostname` property settable through `java.sql.Connection.setClientInfo()`, wouldn't that do the trick in some situations?

Comment: Worth a look @Aaron, but I'm afraid this is to help the database do its thing, not helping me to reach it. I need to play tricks with a firewall, not the database.

Comment: Yes this is most definitely just JDBC metadata, I highly doubt it would change a thing at the network level.

Comment: I would think this is really a host routing issue. The host should create the socket using the best available interface for doing so.

Comment: Indeed, but in this case, I need the second best interface ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some googling suggests that it depends on a particular JDBC driver.

For **MySQL**, it's done via property on the URL:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila?localSocketAddress=123.33.33.33
```

(See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)

In the case of **Postgres**, looks like your best option is `socketFactory` URL property - just create plain old sockets, not SSL sockets.

(See https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html#connection-parameters)

Comment: I'm using Postgres, but that's what I was looking for. Postgres allows to specify a SocketFactory the same way. So I guess there is a way, but it will be database specific...

Answer (score 1):

Following PR add feature to configure localSocketAddress on PostgreSQL JDBC driver: https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/pull/2082